# how to create a auto-login page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

could any one help me how auto login works in wordpress.

Now what I want is when ever a person clicks the link in the email it will redirect to the protected page then it will automatically login base on the userid in the querystring of the link.

example:
site.com/auto-login.php?uid=1234&location=www.site.com/home

Comment: Great, I can finally hack someone without effort. Just insert the admin's UID and I'm inside.

Answer (score -1):

First I have to ask: Are you insane? Because what you're proposing is absolutely insane from a security standpoint. What would anyone hinder to just put the admins uid in the url and instantaneously be admin?

For the love of all that is holy, don't do this! Emails are not encrypted, so in the worst case *everyone* can probably click the link.

It's a bit-shat crazy idea. Don't do it.

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestions.
but the link above is just a example i have an other account that can'ts access the admin side. its a normal user account